# questions about gulp recipe for browserify

Tags: browserify, babeljs

The gulp recipes on github specifically says to use stackexchange for questions instead of bug reports, that's why I am here.

I am looking at the [**Browserify + Globs**](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-with-globs.md) recipe, and I have some questions.

#### Question: what *app.js*?

```
bundledStream
  // turns the output bundle stream into a stream containing
  // the normal attributes gulp plugins expect.
  .pipe(source('app.js'))
  // the rest of the gulp task, as you would normally write it.
  // here we're copying from the Browserify + Uglify2 recipe.
  .pipe(buffer())
```

The example specifically is about using globs to match multiple files. Why do they specify a single `app.js` file? Do I need to actually have some `app.js` somewhere, and if so, what should be in it?

#### Question: is there an alternate form for this?

```
globby(['./entries/*.js']).then(function(entries) {
  // create the Browserify instance.
  var b = browserify({
    entries: entries,
    debug: true,
    transform: [reactify]
  });
```

the whole reason I am looking at this recipe is because I was using `gulp-browserify`, but it is unmaintained and doesn't have `browserify(...).transform()`, and I need to transform with babelify with `presets: es2016, es2015`. And it turns out, you can't just do the obvious thing: `transform: [babelify, {presets: ['es2015','es2016']}]`, because this doesn't work.

Likewise, you can't just rely on the **.babelrc** file and a plain `transform: [babelify]`, because that doesn't work (I see imports *are* working, but destructured parameters like `constructor({val_a=1, val_b})` do not).

Overall, I want to convert this working task:

```
return gulp.src(['dev/scripts/**/*.js', '!dev/scripts/vendor/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(plumber({
        handleError: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            this.emit('end');
        }
    }))
    .pipe(browserify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts'))
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts'))
    .pipe(reload({ stream: true }))
```

to one that uses regular browserify, and babelify with `.transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2016"]})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the form you need is `babelify.configure({})`

My task is working in this form:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  let scripts = ['dev/scripts/**/*.js', '!dev/scripts/vendor/**/*.js']
  let bundledStream = through()

  bundledStream
    .pipe(source('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(plumber({
      handleError: function (err) {
        console.log(err)
        this.emit('end')
      }
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/scripts'))
    .pipe(reload({ stream: true }))

  globby(scripts).then(function(entries) {
    let b = browserify({
      entries: entries,
      debug: true,
      transform: [babelify.configure({
        presets: ["es2016", "es2015"]
      })]
    })

    b.bundle().pipe(bundledStream)
  }).catch(function(err) {
    bundledStream.emit('error', err)
  })

  return bundledStream
})
```